# RocksDB cryptic error message

Tags: rocksdb

Does anyone understand what this RocksDB error refers to ?

> /column_family.cc:275: rocksdb::ColumnFamilyData::~ColumnFamilyData():
>   Assertion `refs_ == 0' failed. Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 2):

This is an assertion failure raised by RocksDB, and it intentionally terminates the execution of the program.

In general, assertions are used by programmers to ensure certain invariants in the program. Assertions have some runtime overhead, and therefore can be completely disabled. Often they are compiled into development or debug builds, but are omitted for production builds.

When an assertion fails, the program execution is intentionally aborted immediately by calling `std::abort`. This may lead to your OS writing a core dump (as it obviously did as the above message reveals), but if and where core dumps are written depends on the OS configuration.

In case of this specific assertion, the destructor of `rocksdb::ColumnFamilyData` raised the assertion because it requires its `refs_` member to have a value of 0. `refs_` is a reference counter and it makes sense to assert that no references are actually held when the object's destructor is called.

From just looking at the destructor code, it is unclear whether this is a bug in the RocksDB library itself, or an error caused by using it the wrong way, e.g. destroying column family objects when they are still in use by other objects.

For reference, here's the code part that raised the assertion (currently on line 365 in file *rocksdb/db/column_family.cc*):

```
ColumnFamilyData::~ColumnFamilyData() {
  assert(refs_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 0);
```

If the error persists, it may be useful if you provide the code that uses RocksDB here. Otherwise it may be impossible to find the error source.
The core dump may also provide useful information, because it contains the stack trace of the code that actually invoked the object's destructor.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that all `column_family.cc` errors (core_dumped, memory_order_relaxed and etc) occur after incorrect rocksdb installation. In my vagrant script i found true way.

instead of use 
https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/master/INSTALL.md

i create script

```
cd /opt 
git clone https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb.git
cd rocksdb
git checkout tags/v4.1

PORTABLE=1 make shared_lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rocksdb
```

LD_LIBRARY_PATH add better to your environment path(.bash_rc or /etc/environment)

Answer (score 0):

Assertion `refs_ == 0` fails on `~ColumnFamilyData()` means the reference count of a column family is not zero when the column family is deleted.  Most likely you have some un-deleted column family handles before closing the DB.  Note that all column family handles must be deleted before closing the DB.  Otherwise the assertion will fail.

```
// Before delete DB, you have to close All column families by calling
// DestroyColumnFamilyHandle() with all the handles.
static Status Open(const DBOptions& db_options, const std::string& name,
                   const std::vector<ColumnFamilyDescriptor>& column_families,
                   std::vector<ColumnFamilyHandle*>* handles, DB** dbptr);
```

To fix such assertion failure, making sure you delete all column family handles before closing the DB.